# How to rotate a multivariable function, such as $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ around the $x$ axis

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

It is easy to find the equation to rotate a multivariable function around the $z$ axis but how would this be done for the $x$ axis.

When rotating a multivariable function around $z$ you get that a new point on the rotated function is given by, $$x'=xcos\theta - ycos\theta$$
$$y'=xsin\theta+ycos\theta$$ and a function can be created from these new variables.

But I have no clue how to approach the rotation when it is done through the $x$ axis, I have tried many methods such as trying to find the how the $f(x,y)$ and $y$ changes when the graph is rotated (since $x$ would be constant for all points throughout the rotation) and from there plugging in the values to create a new function but nothing has worked.

I have noticed that when the function rotates each point is going in a circle of radius $\sqrt{y^2+f(x,y)^2}$ by Pythagoras' theorem, and trying to find a relation between the points on the rotated function and the points on the original function through that, but nothing has worked.

I'm trying to create a general function for any function rotated around any angle about the $x$ axis, if that wasn't clear already.

Comment: You can certainly rotate the implicit equation $f(x,y)-z=0$ in a similar way. The problem is that what you end up with might not be a function any more. Think about what happens in 2-D when you rotate a parabola through an arbitrary angle.

Comment: I'm fairly new to multivariable functions, I only just found out about them a week ago actually. I don't really know anything about them, so if you could clarify a bit more that would be great.

Comment: What you’re trying to do is basically equivalent to rotating the parabola $y=x^2$ around the origin in 2-D. It can be certainly be done and it’s not too hard to come up with an equation for the resulting curve, but the only angles for which you’ll end up with the graph of a function of $x$ are $0$ and $\pi$.

Comment: BTW, what you call rotation about the $x$-$y$ axis is actually rotation about the $z$-axis.

Comment: Using the same method as I would to find an equation to rotate the parabola $y=x^2$ I got two equations.
$$f(x,y)'=f(x,y)cos\theta+ysin\theta$$
$$y'=ycos\theta-f(x,y)sin\theta$$
I don't know if these are even correct, or what to do with them?
I've tried doing,
$$f(x,y)'=(x^2+y^2)cos\theta+(ycos\theta-f(x,y)sin\theta)sin\theta$$
but after graphing it, I found it was wrong.

Comment: $(x^2+y^2)$ is meant to be $f(x,y)$ above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rotation about the $x$-axis looks very much like one about the $z$-axis: $$y' = y\cos\theta-z\sin\theta \\ z' = y\sin\theta+z\cos\theta.\tag1$$ You’re not really rotating a *function*, though: you’re rotating the *graph* of a function, which in this case is a type of surface called a paraboloid of revolution. To do this, you need to start with an implicit Cartesian equation for this surface, such as $$z=x^2+y^2.\tag2$$ The surface is the solution set of this equation. Now you can proceed just as you might have done for the rotation about the $z$-axis: solve (1) for $y$ and $z$ and substitute into (2): $$-y\sin\theta+z\cos\theta = x^2+(y\cos\theta+z\sin\theta)^2.\tag3$$ This is just a quadratic equation in $z$, so solving it for $z$ is easy, though a bit messy, but now there’s a problem: for most combinations of values of $\theta$, $x$ and $y$ we get two (or even no) solutions: $z$ cannot be expressed as a function of $x$ and $y$. The rotated surface doesn’t pass the vertical line test.

This is exactly the same thing that happens in 2-D to the parabola $y=x^2$ when you try to rotate it through an arbitrary angle. Unless the angle is a multiple of $\pi$, you end up with a curve that can’t be the graph of any function of $x$. For example, here’s the parabola rotated 45° counterclockwise:

[image]
It quite obviously fails the vertical line test almost everywhere. Just as in the 3-D case, you can easily write down an equation that describes this curve, but the $x$’s and $y$’s in it don’t separate neatly enough to get a function of $x$.

If you want to read up more on rotations in general, [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)) is a reasonable starting point.

Incidentally, rotating the graph of $z=x^2+y^2$ about the $z$-axis isn’t very interesting (or is quite interesting, depending on your point of view): after simplifying, you just end up with $z=x^2+y^2$ again. The surface is has rotational symmetry and in fact can be generated by rotating a parabola about its axis.

[image]